# Insert rows into an existing SQL Server table where the DateAndTme column should update with one minute difference up to one year in one shot

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Insert rows into an existing SQL Server table where the `DateAndTme` column should update with one minute difference up to one year in one shot and other columns V1,V2,V3 should be NULL.

```
 ValueID | DateAndTime             | V1   | V2   |  V3
 --------+-------------------------+------+------+-----
    1    | 2017-07-28 18:02:00.000 | NULL | NULL | NULL
    2    | 2017-07-28 18:03:00.000 | NULL | NULL | NULL
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add your expected output for the above input here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using tally table.

Create a `function` that generates sequence

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[TallyTable](@MaxNum INT)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
WITH e1(n) AS
(
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
), -- 10
e2(n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM e1 CROSS JOIN e1 AS b), -- 10*10
e3(n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM e1 CROSS JOIN e2), -- 10*100
e4(n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM e3 CROSS JOIN e3 a), -- 1000*1000
e5(n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM e4 CROSS JOIN e4 a), -- 1000000*1000000
res(n) AS (SELECT n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n) FROM e5)
  SELECT n 
  FROM res 
  WHERE n <= @MaxNum
```

Now call the function

```
DECLARE @StartDate  DATETIME,
        @EndDate    DATETIME,
        @MinuteDiff INT

SET @StartDate = '2017-07-28 18:02:00.000'
SET @EndDate = Dateadd(yy, 1, @StartDate)
SET @MinuteDiff = Datediff(minute, @StartDate, @EndDate)

INSERT INTO dbo.ValueTable(DateAndTime, V1, V2, V3)
SELECT DateAndTime = Dateadd(minute, n, @StartDate),
       V1 = NULL,
       V2 = NULL,
       V3 = NULL
FROM   [dbo].[Tallytable](@MinuteDiff)
```

Comment: how do i insert these values into my existing table dbo.ValueTable

Comment: I am very new to this,I have tried your Sql Query but I get this error  Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_ValueTable'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.ValueTable'. The duplicate key value is (1).

Comment: @Srini - does `ValueId` column has `identity` property ?

Comment: when i see the property the it shows Identity is YES and Identity increment is 1 and identity seed is 1

Comment: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ValueID', table 'taclogdata1.dbo.ValueTable'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Comment: @Srini - Did you set `Identity_insert` on ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with dates as (
      select cast('2017-01-01 00:00:00' as datetime) as dte
      union all
      select dateadd(minute, 1, dte)
      from dates
      where dte < '2017-01-02'
     )
select row_number() over (order by dte) as ValueId, dte,
       NULL as v1, NULL as v2, NULL as v3
from dates
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

The `maxrecursion` option is important.  Otherwise you are limited to 100 rows.